How to Prove $ E[X^2Y^2] \leq E[X^2]E[Y^2] $
I'm working on a problem involving the expectations and variances of random variables, and I encountered a step that I'm not sure how to prove rigorously. Specifically, I need to show that:
$ E[X^2Y^2] \leq E[X^2]E[Y^2] $
I understand that this seems related to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but I'm not sure how to apply it correctly in this context. Here are the conditions I'm working with:

( X ) and ( Y ) are random variables.
I do not assume that ( X ) and ( Y ) are independent.
I know also that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.

Could someone please provide a detailed proof or explanation for why $ E[X^2 Y^2] \leq E[X^2]E[Y^2] $?
Thanks in advance for your help!

You wish then show that $X^2$ and $Y^2$ have a negative covariance, right?

In other words, yeah!

It's not true.  Consider the case $Y = X^2$ where $X$ is uniform on $[-1,1]$.  Then
$$\mathbb E[X^2 Y^2] = \mathbb E[X^6] = \frac17$$ while $$\mathbb E[X^2]\;\mathbb E[Y^2] = \mathbb E[X^2]\; \mathbb E[X^4] = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{15}$$

Beautiful example :-)

Here is another pdf defined on unit square $$\frac{1}{2} \left(13-3 \sqrt{17}\right) x^2+2 \left(\sqrt{17}-5\right) x y+4 y^2.$$ The desired covariance is $\frac{7 \left(26-6 \sqrt{17}\right)}{16200}>0$.
